# Is it possible to deal with 2 table engines at the same time? InnoDB with MyISAM

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I was trying to make a full-text search for a simple engine and i have realized i can not do it with InnoDB.

Now, i was wondering if I can convert only that table to MyISAM and still working with the others ones at the same time. This table has a foreign key with another table which is at the same time related with many others.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  5.6 supports `FULLTEXT` indexes/search on InnoDB.  No version (yet) supports foreign key constraints with MyISAM.

Comment: In that case, you can either: upgrade, drop your fulltext indexes, or drop your foreign key constraints.

Comment: MySQL Workbench CE for Windows version 5.2.42  revision 9752

Comment: Won't I lose my DB if i upgrade?

Comment: Sorry, i have MySQL server 5.5. Do you know if it supports fulltexts? When checking for updates it says to me that i am UP TO DATE. There are no updates available.

Comment: Fulltext for InnoDB comes with 5.6 IIRC. It's out already. I bet you are using Linux and it's simply not in the repository already. But you can install it manually.